# Identify the exception to be used from the traceback

Tags: python

I want to catch an exception when user fails login due to wrong password .
So i make a function using imaplib .I enter a wrong password and get a traceback with error details.
       Now my question is actually general.How do you identify the exception we have to mention in our "try and except" body from the error messages?

These is what I got->

```
>>> count("testarc31@gmail.com","Xbox@36")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    count("testarc31@gmail.com","Xbox@36")
  File "E:\Arindam\py_progs\Mail Notifier\0.0.19\Mail.py", line 24, in count
    obj.login(m,p)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\imaplib.py", line 500, in login
    raise self.error(dat[-1])
error: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
```

If i want to make a try and except,what will i mention in the exception part?

```
 try:
    login(mail,pass):
 except ????:
    something
```

Question :

1) What will be ???? here . Can it be deduced directly from the error report?

2) Is there a basic idea to identify what is the exception we have to use from each error we get ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use something like this:

```
try:
    ..code that might raise an exception...
except ExceptionType, e:
    ...do something...
```

In your case, that probably want this:

```
try:
    login(mail,pass)
except imaplib.IMAP4.error, e:
    print "Ouch -- an error from imaplib!"
```

To identify the type of an exception, you can look at its exception message.  In this case it's just "error" -- unfortunately the module name is not included.  You can get a better idea of exactly where it comes from by doing:

```
try:
    login(mail,pass)
except Exception, e:
    print type(e)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that did the job...........Just one question. Whats that 'e' in the except part? I thought we only mention one parameter beside "except". Is there any special significance of that "e"?

Comment: The `,e` is optional.  If you include it, then you'll get a variable named `e` (or whatever you said after the comma) that holds the exception itself.  E.g., in my last example, that's what I used to print the type of the exception object (the variable `e`).